# Visual Studio (2022) 17.7 FTPS to Filezilla wont work

Tags: visual-studio, ftp

I've setup the connection to my Filezilla server like;

ftps://ftp.mydomian.com:888

and the connection validates, under passive mode, but I cant transfer any files I get;

Unable to build data connection: TLS session of data connection not resumed (425)

and in the ftp server logs;

TLS session of data connection not resumed

The FTP server only supports TLS 1.2 and above (which I believe is ok for 2022 VS).

If I drop back to insecure regular FTP all is good.
I have tried switching off all firewalls
Tried with passive mode on/off

Any one have any ideas
Thanks

Comment: I think your problem relates to re-using the sessionId from control channel to data channel. It is a security feature which FTPS server can be set to require. Are you able to configure your client to support this?

Comment: @Jokkeri his client is Visual Studio 2022 and his server is FileZilla FTP Server. Visual Studio does not allow changing how the sessionId is used

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jokkeri though.

Comment: Are you able to control Filezilla settings? If so, try to change the "Require TLS session resumption on data connection when using PROT P" or set TLSOptions "NoSessionReuseRequired". If you cannot control the actual FileZilla, you can always try to proof this on installing filezilla locally.  Screenshot of setting: [link](https://www.adamintech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/FileZilla-server-options-tls.jpg)

Comment: That setting is no longer available as it was deemed to insecure to switch off. Thanks